# can't find syntax error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

have anyone can tell me what syntax error on this actionscript (actionscript3.0)?

```
 var rotY: Number = (mouseY – (stage.stageHeight / 2)) / (stage.height / 2) * 400;
```

Thank for advance.

Comment: stage.height => stage.stageHeight or remove space before than Number declaration?

Comment: but I still get the same error - 1093:Syntax error

Comment: please post the error message.

Comment: "1093:Syntax error" what I get from error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you copy this statement from somewhere ? because in your statement

```
var rotY: Number = (mouseY – (stage.stageHeight / 2)) / (stage.height / 2) * 400;
```

minus symbol after mouseY is actullay dash , char code 8211

In @shanethehat's statement

```
var rotY:Number = (mouseY - (stage.stageHeight / 2)) / (stage.height / 2) * 400;
```

it is the correct minus symbol , char code 45

see : http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/characters/#dash

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this (or just type your line of code out again) and see if you still get an error:

```
var rotY:Number = (mouseY - (stage.stageHeight / 2)) / (stage.height / 2) * 400;
```

I couldn't figure out what it was, but it seems like one of the braces isn't really there in your code.  I typed it out again and it compiled straight away.